# Restructure 2 functors to avoid double implementation

Tags: types, module, ocaml, functor

(* I would like to reformulate a question that I posted previously to make it clearer and attract more attention... I think the question is still interesting... *)

I have defined a module type `ZONE` as follows:

```
(* part of zone.ml *)
module type ZONE =
sig
  type info
  type prop
  type t = { s: string; p: prop; i: info }
  val f1 : t -> string
end
```

where `i: info` is used to contain various information, which help avoid repeat calculation. It will not be always the same because it is up to the `Prop` from which a `Zone` is built. For instance, here is a functor to build a module `Zone` of type `ZONE` from a module of type `PROP`, with a basic `info`:

```
(* part of zone.ml *)
module ZoneFun (Prop : PROP) = struct
  type info = { a: int }
  type prop = Prop.t
  type t = { s: string; p: prop; i: info }
  let f0 z = "f0"
  ...
end
```

Here is another functor to build a module `Zone` of type `ZONE`, with a relatively more complicated `info`:

```
(* zoneFunPrec.ml *)
module ZoneFunPrec (Prop: PROP) (Prec: ZONESM) = struct
  type info = { a: int; b: Prec.t }
  type prop = Prop.t
  type t = { s: string; p: prop; i: info }
  let get_prec z = z.info.prec
  let f0 z = "f0"
  ...
end
```

Then I can use the functors as follows:

```
module ZoneC = ZoneFun(PropC)
module ZoneA = ZoneFunPrec(PropA)(ZonesmB)
```

The problem is that, `type info` and `get_prec` (`ZoneFun` has it, whereas `ZoneFunPrec` hasn't) are the only differences of these 2 functors; their `type prop` and `type t` are same, their functions `f0`, `f1`... (there are quite several) are exactly same too.

So I am wondering how to avoid from implementing `f0`, `f1`, etc. twice...

Does anyone have an idea of restructuring the modules/functors to achieve this and make them meaningful?

Comment: Please try the problem as small as possible and make it compilable. Your code contains too much meaningless details to answerers, not complete, and not compilable. ZoneFunPrec(ProcC) is wrong. It must be  ZoneFun(ProcC)

Comment: You are right about `ZoneFun(ProcC)`, just amended...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a module which only contains the shared patterns:

```
module Shared = struct
  type prop = Prop.t
  type t = { s: string; p: prop; i: info }
  let f0 z = "f0"
  ...
end
```

I believe here your real `f0` is more complex and depends on other things in your code. (Otherwise it can be just defined outside of the context separately.)

This module `Shared` is not really compilable since it contains some free names like `Prop` and `info`. Change it to a functor which takes these names from its parameter:

```
module MakeShared(A : sig
  module Prop : sig
    type t
  end
  type info
end) = struct
  type prop = Prop.t
  type t = { s : string; p : prop; i : info }
  let f0 z = "f0"
  ...
end
```

You may need more things in the signature for `A`. It depends on the code you omitted.

You can use this `MakeShared` functor in the body of `ZoneFun` and `ZoneFunPrec` to avoid code duplication. It should be like:

```
module ZoneFun (Prop : PROP) = struct
  type info = { a: int }
  type info_ = info
  include MakeShared(struct
    module Prop = Prop
    type info = info_
  end)
end
```

Here the type alias `info_` is required to avoid the cyclic recusvie type definition `type info = info`. Unlike `module` which is not recursive therefore `module Prop = Prop` works as intended, `type` declaration is always recursive.

This is one way to refactor your code. There may be others but it is not very clear from your pseudo code. For example you may be able to use MakeShared not inside the functor but where you create an actual instance module:

```
module ZoneC = struct
  include SmallerZoneFun(PropC)
  include MakeShared(...)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have the exact code for you, but couldn't you stick the common functions in their own `module` and then `include` it like:

```
module type ZONE =
sig
  type info
  type prop
  type t = { s: string; p: prop; i: info }
  include ZoneFunCommon
end
```